# React Native screen renders twice - only after back button exit

Tags: android, react-native

I'm facing an issue in my React Native app that only exists when re-opening the app after it has been exiting by the Android back button.  The screen loads once with all the data, and then re-loads again, and this does not occur if opening the app for the first time, or activating the app when in background mode. So the outcome is an annoying and slow, where the screen flashes when reloading the second time.

Is this normal behavior? It seems as if the previously screen is loaded, and then re-rendered.

Any ideas of causes?

-- edit --

I've commented out any potential useState() changes, and this did not prevent the issue.

whether opening the app for the first time, or after a back button open, the following will output render view twice.

```
useEffect( () => {
  console.log('render view')
}, [])
```